How can I use ACME.sh on OpenWRT to renew a Let's Encrypt certificate without opening my web server to the Internet
I run an OpenWRT router with uhttpd providing a UI to the internal LAN.  But I block ports 80 and 443 on the WAN side, for safety.  I'd like to use ACME.sh to renew my certificates but I can't use the DNS method with my DNS provider because I am a cheapskate: you can only use the DNS method at freedns if you have a domain and I only have subdomain.
To use the standalone method I am obviously going to have to open port 80.  But I don't want to allow any of those incoming packets to get to uhttpd - I want to be very sure they can't.  So I thought I could redirect WAN:80 to LAN:8080 and get ACME to listen on 8080.  However, there doesn't seem to be a way to get ACME to listen on 8080.
I tried just editing the ACME script to use port 8080 and then everything works.  But that's obviously not a useful solution.  Am I missing something simpler?

So the solution I am using is just to stop uhttpd from listening on port 80.  Initially I stopped it using http entirely by editing /etc/config/uhttpd and removing the two lines that say
list listen_http '0.0.0.0:80'
list listen_http '[::]:80'

I then had a problem when I mis-configured the certificate so the https connections stopped working and I could no longer contact uhttpd and LUCI.  So I decided instead to simply use a different port - I chose 8080 and added the removed lines back but changed to:
list listen_http '0.0.0.0:8080'
list listen_http '[::]:8080'

Either way, this works with the standard luci-app-acme installation. The ACME script can redirect port 80 when it needs it since nothing else is listening on that port.  Browsers on the LAN can no longer use port 80 to access uhhtpd but you can still use http://<router-address>:8080 and, once your certificate is working, https://<router-dns>.
It is, I think, possible to not use the luci-app-acme GUI and use manual configuration of ACME instead, and the configuration suggested in the question.  The ACME script does, according to the documentation, take an httpport parameter which could be set to 8080.  However, it does not seem to be possible to use that through the LUCI ACME interface, which is very bare bones.
